# If values from two columns match, insert value from a third column into a fourth

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Hoping to pull from zip code values in column H (sheet 1) and column B (sheet 2), if the zip codes in sheet 1 match the zip codes in sheet 2 then populate the neighborhood value from column C (sheet 2) into column L (sheet 1).

Huge excel novice, looking for a hand. Thanks!

I've tried

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet2!B:B,H:H,0))
```

---

EDIT: 
trying to have the locations from Column C in the first image below appear in Column L of the second image IF the zip codes in both Column B of the first image and Column H of the second match.

1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfy2A.png
2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtGLa.png

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you post a screenshot, what the data and the expected result looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(H1,Sheet2!B:B,0))=C1,C1,"")
```